# Create an interactive map in Java with shapefiles

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, openstreetmap, openlayers, java

How can I create an interactive map in Netbeans by using a shapefile of world map? Which of below options are suitable? OpenLayers, OpenStreepMap, GeoServer and WMP?

How can they help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [shapelib](http://shapelib.maptools.org/)   .You will find Java for basic Shapefile operations.For advanced operations you may want to try [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/main.htm) .http://www.openjump.org/ is another Java based tool.All these are Desktop solutions.Plenty of options are listed out [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/geospatial)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i use Openlayers by adding shapefiles?

Comment: I think so , with GWT wrapper @ http://www.gwt-openlayers.org/.But I have no experience in Java.